# Generalized conjugacy classes in (topological) groups

Tags: gr.group-theory, measure-theory, finite-groups, harmonic-analysis, topological-groups

Let $G$ be a topological group. We define an  equivalence relation on $G$ as follows:

For $a,b\in G$ we set $a\sim b$ if the following two maps are topologically conjugate:

$$x\mapsto ax,\qquad x\mapsto bx$$

By topological conjugacy of two maps $f, g$ on a  topological space $G$ we mean, as usual, existence of a homeomorphism $H:G\to G$  with $Hf=gH$.

Obviously the usual group theoretical conjugate elements are equivalent in this new sense. But possibly the  equivalence classes are larger than algebraic conjugacy class.

In the  finite  (discrete ) group case  the equivalence relation is the following: two elements are equivalent if the  corresponding permutations are  conjugate in $P(G)$, the  permutation group of $G$.

**My first question:**

> In the  finite group case, the  cardinality of the conjugacy class of an element $a$ is  $\frac{|G|}{|C(a)|}$  where $C(a)$ is  the centralizer of $a$. Now  what is a  formula for  the  cardinality of an equivalence class containing $a$. I mean a formula in terms of $G$ itself  not in terms of $P(G)$. More precisely can  we canonically associate a  subgroup $\tilde{C}(a)\subset G$   to  every element $a\in G$ such that the  equivalence class $[a]$ is in bijection correspondance to $\tilde{C}(a)$ in a canonical way. Another question: From undergraduate group theory I remember that various  equivalence relations on finite groups enable us to obtain some useful  counting theorems. Even Sylow's theorems were direct or undirect  consequence of  some equivalence relations. So I wonder is this  equivalence relation useful to produce some  new counting results?

**My second  question:**

> For the  obvious case $G=\mathbb{R}$ we get triviality. There are only two equivalence classes. On the  other hand for  circle case every equivalence class is the  (singleton) conjugacy class since the rotation number is a topological invariant. Are there examples for which the measure of  an equivalence class approach to zero  or  approach to 1 (w.r.t. the  Haar measure)?
> That means: can one produce a sequence of example such that an equivalent class has  measure $1/n$ or $1-1/n$? This possibly prevent us to give finite group example.

However one should first answer  to: **Is every equivalence class necessarily measurable?**

Comment: For a finite group two elements are equivalent if and only if they have the same order. This is because if g has order n then it acts as a disjoint union of |G|/n n-cycles corresponding to the cosets

Comment: The number of elements of order dividing n divides the order of the group but not the number of elements of order exactly n.

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg  Thank you for your interesting comment. Since "order" plays a crucial role so your comment is a motivation to consider a concept of order for elements of a topological group. The order is not a number but is an equivalent class.

Comment: It is an **equivalence** relation and an **equivalence** class.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Thank you for your correction

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg In fact the order can a non natural number as in the case of circle $\theta$ can be count as an order of $e^{i\theta}$ in $S^1$

Comment: @MoisheKohan I would appreciate if you give comment on the following question:

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg  What would be an apprpriate analogues of Caley theorem? On the other jand assume that $H$ is a closed subgroup of $G$. Assume that $a,b\in H$ are equivalent as elements of H are they equivalent as elements of $G$? this question is obvious for the algebraic conjugacy but what about topological congugacy?

Comment: Most likely the answer is positive but I do not have a proof.

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg I wonder if the measurability of each algebraic conjugqcy class or topological conjugacy class is an obvious question

Comment: @MoisheKohan please read my previous comment

Comment: In a discrete group $G$, $g,h$ are equivalent iff $g$, $h$ have the same order and the (possibly infinite) index of $\langle g\rangle$ and $\langle h\rangle$ is the same. (If $G$ is not virtually infinite cyclic, the latter condition can be dropped.)